# FactoryBot end as a table fiel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm having problems creating some factories, when the database was created someone called a field of a table like "end" now when I try to build the factory when i I type end and then try to assign a value it takes that en as the end of the factory not as an atribute of the table.

Any Idea of how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use a `reserved` word as an attribute name in your factory definitions. This is how you can do it:

```
factory :enrique_table do
  add_attribute(:end) { 'just the beginning' }
end
```

`add_attribute` method let's you define attributes with `reserved` words. If you like to learn more about `FactoryBot`, head over to their [Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#method-name--reserved-word-attributes) guide.

Hope it helps.

Comment: andHapp thanks for your help, It worked, I had clear end is a reserved word, unfurnately I did not do the database design, and the person who did it maybe did not realise it could be a conflict any time. Once again thanks for your help it worked perfectly